# Microsoft DependencyInjection: ServiceProviderFactory doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Please checkout the below codes

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

IServiceProviderFactory<IServiceCollection> serviceProviderFactory =
    new DefaultServiceProviderFactory(new ServiceProviderOptions {
        ValidateOnBuild = true,
        ValidateScopes = true
    });
IServiceCollection oldServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
IServiceCollection newServiceCollection =
    serviceProviderFactory.CreateBuilder(oldServiceCollection);
Assert.IsTrue(oldServiceCollection == newServiceCollection);
```

I wanted to create a `newServiceCollection` base on the `oldServiceCollection` (then modify the `newServiceCollection`). However (big surprise) the `ServiceProviderFactory`, despite being a "Factory" with "Create.." methods, it did not create anything...

The `newServiceCollection` IS the `oldServiceCollection`. (If I modified the `newServiceCollection` then the `oldServiceCollection` will be modified as well).

I think that "DefaultServiceProviderFactory" (of Microsoft) is at fault here, do anybody know a better implementation which can help me clone the `oldServiceCollection` to make a `newServiceCollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [by design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6072e4d3a7a2a1493f514cdf4be75a3d56580e84/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/DefaultServiceProviderFactory.cs#L42). The `DefaultServiceProviderFactory` isn't useful and only exists for other DI Containers to intercept the creation of `IServiceCollection` instances.

To make a copy, you'll have to iterate the old collection and add all ServiceDescriptors to the new one:

```cs
var newServiceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

foreach (var descriptor in oldServiceCollection)
{
    newServiceCollection.Add(descriptor);
}
```